# jenkins under docker on windows, can't access localost

Tags: docker, jenkins

i'm trying to run jenkins under docker on my win10 machine
with this command I start the container :

```
 docker run --restart=always -d -u root -p 9090:8080 -p 50000:50000  -v "E:\docker\Jenkins":/var/jenkins_home  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  --name jenkins jenkins
```

that's how the result of ps -a looks like

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
36ef88027e3e        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->8080/tcp   jenkins
```

the problem - there is nothing on localhost 9090

and when I check it with this command the result is - no value

```
 docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" jenkins
<no value>
```

but docker logs shows me out put from jenkins start and all looks normal

what do I miss?

Comment: If `docker inspect` does return you an IP address, it's basically useless in many contexts.  For example, it's specifically called out as not being reachable in the [Docker for Windows documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible).  I'd just never run this `docker inspect` command.

Comment: Works for me without issues. Would you mind sharing output of `docker version` and `ver` commands?